# Using max<int> as a predicate breaks in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In C++03 the following code works fine:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2.push_back(2);
    v2.push_back(3);
    v2.push_back(4);

    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.begin(), std::max<int>);
    return 0;
}
```

In C++11 this doesn't work because it added an overload for `std::max` that contains an `initializer_list`. Therefore, you have to use a very ugly cast to choose the correct overload:

```
static_cast<const int& (*)(const int&, const int&)>(std::max)
```

I have a few questions.

- Why did the standard committee decide to do this knowing it would (probably) break existing code and force the user to create an ugly cast?
- Are future standards of C++ going to attempt to alleviate this problem?
- What is a workaround?

Comment: You may still use lambda instead of the cast.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are supposed to explicitly list the type arguments to template functions like `std::max` and use them as functors just because they are in STL and it is allowed by syntax

Comment: @PiotrS. : The C++ standard does have footnotes, which cover the "you're [not] supposed to" angle. It's not a mere specification. But there's no note on this particular usage. Nor is there a claim that the footnotes are a complete set of suggestions.

Comment: The answer to bullet one: *"Seemed like a good idea at the time."* :) I wouldn't be surprised if it turns out that nobody in the committee saw this coming.

Comment: Not an answer because I can't check it at this time, but isn't the implementation allowed to add default arguments and/or overloads anyway? That would make the code already non-compliant by C++03 standards, even if it usually worked.

Comment: @MSalters Extra default arguments aren't allowed for global or non-member functions. Extra signatures are allowed though.

Comment: @T.C. So `std::max(T a, T b, T c)` was already legal and therefore the code above already was flawed in C++03? Makes sense.

Comment: @MSalters Technically, `T a, T b, T c` probably wasn't legal - it breaks in the pathological case when `T` is also used as the comparator. Four `T`s though might be.

Comment: I can think of at least one more function template that will no longer work if in C++03 one tried to explicitly specify the types rather than allow compiler deduce them, which is `std::make_pair`. It previously took arguments by value, so that `make_pair<int,int>` resulted in `make_pair(int, int)`, where as in C++11 it takes forwarding references, which results in `make_pair(int&&, int&&)`. So the point I'm trying to make is that one should not specify the types explicitly for `std` template functions. Another thing is that there can be non-templated overloads that already take e.g. `int`.

Comment: The "*max<int> as predicate fails in C++11*" issue has been presented in [GoingNative 2013: Don't Help the Compiler](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Don-t-Help-the-Compiler) @ 0:50:47, with a rule: *"don't use explicit template arguments"*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are doing this sufficiently frequently, you might want to write a transparent functor wrapper:

```
struct my_max {
    template<class T>
    const T& operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const{
        return std::max(a, b);
    }
};
```

Then you can simply do

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.begin(), my_max());
```

whenever you need it, rather than writing a lambda or a cast each time. This is basically the same idea as the transparent operator functors - let the template arguments be deduced at the actual call site rather than explicitly specified when you create the functor.

If you want to make this fancier, you can even have `operator()` take heterogeneous types and add perfect forwarding and use trailing return types:

```
struct my_max {
    template<class T, class U>
    constexpr auto operator()( T&& t, U&& u ) const
      -> decltype(t < u ? std::forward<U>(u) : std::forward<T>(t)){
        return t < u ? std::forward<U>(u) : std::forward<T>(t);
    }
};
```

In C++14, this is simplified to

```
struct my_max {
    template<class T, class U>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()( T&& t, U&& u ) const{
        return t < u ? std::forward<U>(u) : std::forward<T>(t);
    }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you just use two separate template parameters and trailing return types?

Comment: What I'm hoping to see is a transparent comparator syntax like `std::less<>()`, i.e. `std::max<>()`.

Comment: @user4112979 Well, `std::less` is a class template. `std::max` is a function template.

Comment: Be warned that the forwarding version will break horribly in the (somewhat pathological) case when `T` or `U` is a type with a "stealing" move ctor, either `t` or `u` is an r-value reference and `<` takes the appropriate operand by value.

Comment: @Angew Good point, I guess I'll remove the forward for the `<` part, though it might break in some other pathological case instead. Oh well.

Comment: A `forward` should only happen at the **last** use of a perfectly forwarded variable as a rule.  Oh, and think about for the first version taking `Ts...` to be fully transparent.  For the second, consider using `std::less<void>` instead of `<` to get proper behavior for pointers.

Comment: @Yakk I don't see much point in forwarding to `std::max` - it drops the value category on the ground anyway. `std::less` specialized for a pointer type provides a total order; `std::less<void>` doesn't.

Comment: @T.C. oh, `std::less<void>` failing on pointers is sad.  *sniff*

Comment: @Yakk I suppose you could add an extra overload for pointers only...but it's a lot of complication for a scenario that `std::max` doesn't really support anyway...

Comment: @T.C. could you tell why this is written as `t < u ? std::forward<U>(u) : std::forward<T>(t);` and not `std::forward<T>(t) < std::forward<U>(u) ? u : t` ? isn't the `?:` operator suppose to get `common_type` of operands, so that returning forward results in something *common* ? and shouldn't the forwarding forward the arguments to *some* `operator<` instead of calling it with plain `t` and `u` ?

Comment: @MarcAndreson Forwarding to `<` will break if `t` or `u` got moved from during the call to `operator<` - see Angew's comment above. You would be constructing the return value from a moved-from object.

Comment: @T.C. ahh, and for the second issue, is there a point in forwarding operands, if the result is `common_type<type of std::forward<T>(t), type of std::forward<U>(u)>` ? i can't think of what it actually does

Comment: @MarcAndreson It constructs the return value by moving when the selected argument is an rvalue.

Comment: @MarcAndreson ?: and common_type give different types, the second one does a decay on the result of the first one.

Comment: @MarcGlisse ahh but I am not sure if `decltype(auto)` will work as expected due to this `?:` operator, as the declared return type must be something "common" for operands of `?:` which are references, maybe I am just wrong

Comment: @MarcAndreson Depending on the types and value categories of its second and third operands, the result of `?:` can be an lvalue, an xvalue or a prvalue. [The full set of rules](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24706610/2756719) is rather long. `decltype(auto)` will capture the value category appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

> What is a workaround?

A lambda is probably the most readable and useful for predicates and comparators:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.begin(),
               [] (int a, int b) {return std::max(a,b);} );
```

You might want to check out T.C.s functor if you need it more often. Or, with C++14:

```
auto max = [] (auto&& a, auto&& b) -> decltype(auto)
  {return a > b? std::forward<decltype(a)>(a) : std::forward<decltype(b)>(b);};
```

> Why did the standard committee decide to do this knowing it would
>   (probably) break existing code and force the user to create an ugly
>   cast?

The only explanation is that they found the new overload to bring enough joy to compensate the breaking of existing code and the need for workarounds in future.
You could just use `std::max_element` instead of this new overload, so you trade the syntax sugar for passing `std::max`-specializations as predicates for the syntax sugar of finding the maximum element within a couple of variables without explicitly creating an array for it.

Basically

```
std::transform( ..., std::max<int> );
// <=>
std::transform( ..., [] (int a, int b) {return std::max(a,b);} );
```

vs

```
int arr[] {a,b,c,d}; // You don't have an array with a,b,c,d included consecutively yet
int maximum = *std::max_element( std::begin(arr), std::end(arr) ); // ensure arr non-empty!
// <=>
auto maximum = std::max({a, b, c, d});
```

Maybe it does compensate? On the other hand, you barely ever need the latter.

> Are future standards of C++ going to attempt to alleviate this
>   problem?

I don't think so. Apparently, the standard committee really doesn't like to remove recently introduced features. I don't really see that much of a problem either; The lambda does the job.

Comment: There's not much point in forwarding if you are passing it over to `std::max`, since it throws the value category on the floor anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Although I've accepted [T.C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26215699/4112979) which provides a comprehensive breakdown, as stated in a comment, I want to mimic the transparent comparator functor for class templates like `std::less`. This answer is provided for critique by others incase there's anything wrong with the syntax.

```
template <typename T = void>
struct my_max;

template <>
struct my_max<void> {
    template<class T, class U>
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()( T&& t, U&& u ) const {
        return t < u ? std::forward<U>(u) : std::forward<T>(t);
    }
};
```

Comment: Indeed, as a rule of thumb, an argument should not be forwarded more than once.

Comment: As inspired by `less`, why not invoke it?  Always perfect forward, and always call `std::less<X>` in `my_max<X>`.

Comment: Why did you not provide a definition for the primary template? Is this intended?

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with using C++20 ranges additions you can just use `std::ranges::max`.

`std::ranges::max` is not a function, but a struct so it can be passed to the algorithms.

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/bfWjcf4Pc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2.push_back(2);
    v2.push_back(3);
    v2.push_back(4);

    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.begin(), std::ranges::max);
    std::cout << fmt::format("{}", v2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have recent boost you can use `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` macro.

fmt lib in [example](https://godbolt.org/z/oo3vfMs6d) is just for printing vector, all you need is boost

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/hof/lift.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    std::vector<int> v2;
    v2.push_back(2);
    v2.push_back(3);
    v2.push_back(4);

    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v2.begin(), v2.begin(), BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::max<int>));
    std::cout << fmt::format("{}", v2);
}
```

Comment: using macro (especially from boost) is a pretty ugly solution. Also using BOOST in such a case implies introducing a huge and unnecessary dependency just to use `std::max` in `std::transform`, both of which are a part of std

Comment: Boost is great, and widely avaliable so I disagree

Comment: Boost is not great, it is mostly outdated and is bloated with macros. Though nobody tells you that you shouldn't like it. That's an *opinion*. But introducing a huge library (BOOST is huge and it's a *fact*) as a dependency just for something a simple lambda can solve is such an overkill. It's not like using a canon where a hammer is enough. It's like using a Spanish Armada

Comment: Nobody is forcing you to use entire boost. Many people are already using it so I dont consider this a huge problem. Obviously I doubt anybody would introduce boost just for HOF, but in my experience most C++ companies already use it...

Comment: in the context of this question *you* are the one who suggests introducing BOOST just for `HOF`. There was no mentioning of BOOST in the question