# Initializing lvalue reference with rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

I built this code with gcc/clang and got different results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istream& is = 1 ? std::move(std::stringstream("")) : std::cin;
}
```

- Why gcc allows initializing lvalue reference with rvalue (`std::stringstream("")`)?
- Why clang tries to call copy constructor?

### gcc 4.9.1

No error

### clang 3.4

```
prog.cc:5:63: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'istream' (aka 'basic_istream<char>')
    std::istream& is = 1 ? std::move(std::stringstream("")) : std::cin;
                                                             ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/libcxx-3.4/include/c++/v1/istream:185:5: note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' has a user-declared move constructor
   basic_istream(basic_istream&& __rhs);
   ^
prog.cc:5:28: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
   std::istream& is = 1 ? std::move(std::stringstream("")) : std::cin;
                          ^
/usr/local/libcxx-3.4/include/c++/v1/istream:185:5: note: declared protected here
   basic_istream(basic_istream&& __rhs);
   ^
prog.cc:5:28: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >'
   std::istream& is = 1 ? std::move(std::stringstream("")) : std::cin;
                          ^
/usr/local/libcxx-3.4/include/c++/v1/istream:185:5: note: declared protected here
   basic_istream(basic_istream&& __rhs);
   ^
```

Comment: I know what clang is doing, and it's correct. I have no idea what GCC is doing.

Comment: Seems to be the `std::move` that confuses GCC.  Without it, it will give a proper error.  This is strange because the `std::move` is actually redundant here anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GCC's behavior is a bug, and it's [been fixed on trunk](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tH9lAUIVKzI86cGU). Clang is correct. This is a messy case because you have mixed value categories for the second and third operands of the conditional operator:

- `std::move(std::stringstream(""))` is an xvalue<sup>*</sup> of type `std::stringstream`;
- `std::cin` is an lvalue of type `std::istream`.

The relevant standard quote (§5.16 [expr.cond]/p3-6) can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24706610/2756719). It's long enough that I don't really want to copy it over. I'll just outline how it is applied to this code:

- Obviously `std::istream` cannot be converted to match `std::stringstream` in any way regardless of value category;
- An xvalue of type `std::stringstream` cannot be converted to type "lvalue reference to `std::istream`" given the constraint that the reference must bind directly to an lvalue - there's no lvalue here for the reference to bind to;
- `std::istream` is a base class of `std::stringstream`, so per the 3rd bullet of p3,  the xvalue of type `std::stringstream` can and will be converted to a prvalue temporary of type `std::istream` by copy-initialization, which replaces the original operand for further analysis.
- Now the second operand is a prvalue of type `std::istream`, the third operand is an lvalue of type `std::istream`, they have different value categories so p4 doesn't apply.
- Hence the result is a prvalue per p5. Since they have the same type, overload resolution specified in p5 is not performed, and you proceed to p6.
- The applicable bullet in p6 is

  > The second and third operands have the same type; the result is of
  >   that type. If the operands have class type, the result is a prvalue
  >   temporary of the result type, which is copy-initialized from either
  >   the second operand or the third operand depending on the value of the
  >   first operand.

  so it copy-initializes the result (which is a prvalue temporary) from either the converted first operand, or the second operand (`std::cin`).

Hence the errors:

- Copy-initializing the prvalue `std::istream` result from an lvalue (`std::cin`) would use the copy constructor, and streams cannot be copied.
- Copy-initializing the prvalue temporary `std::istream` for the second operand from a `std::stringstream` xvalue is a move, but `std::istream`'s move constructor is protected.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> For terminology (lvalue, xvalue, prvalue, etc.), see [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)</sub>