# Incompatible operand types when using ternary conditional operator

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

This code:

```
bool contains = std::find(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), i) != indexes.end();
CardAbility* cardAbility = contains ? new CardAbilityBurn(i) : new CardAbilityEmpty;
```

gives me the following error:

> Incompatible operand types CardAbilityBurn and CardAbilityEmpty

However if I write the code like this:

```
if (contains)
{
    cardAbility = new CardAbilityBurn(i);
}
else
{
    cardAbility = new CardAbilityEmpty;
}
```

... then the compiler doesn't mind. Why so? I want to use ternary conditional operator because it is just one line. What's wrong there?

I need to note (I think you might need this information) that `CardAbilityEmpty` and `CardAbilityBurn` both derive from `CardAbility` so they are so to say brothers.

Comment: Essentially same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706480. Simplest fix is to explicitly convert one of them to `CardAbility*`.

Comment: Really interresting question.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? On VS2008 it works with derived classes.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Apple LLVM 6.0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does std::istringstream appear to resolve differently to std::ifstream in the ternary (?:) operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706480/why-does-stdistringstream-appear-to-resolve-differently-to-stdifstream-in-th)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C++'s type system determines expressions' types from the inside out<sup>[1]</sup>. That means that the conditional expression's type is determined before the assignment to `CardAbility*` is made, and the compiler has to choose with only `CardAbilityBurn*` and `CardAbilityEmpty*`.

As C++ features multiple inheritance and some more possible conversion paths, since none of the types is a superclass of the other the compilation stops there.

To compile successfully, you need to provide the missing part : cast one or both operands to the base class type, so the conditional expression as a whole can take that type.

```
auto* cardAbility = contains
    ? static_cast<CardAbility*>(new CardAbilityBurn(i))
    : static_cast<CardAbility*>(new CardAbilityEmpty  );
```

(Note the use of auto, since you already provided the destination type in the right-side expression.)

It *is* however a bit convoluted, so in the end the `if`-`else` structure is better-suited in this case.

[1] There is one exception : overloaded function names have no definitive type until you convert them (implicitly or explicitly) to one of their versions.

Answer (score 2):

There are [several cases described for Microsoft compilers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx), how to handle operand types.

> If both operands are of the same type, the result is of that type.
>
> If both operands are of arithmetic or enumeration types, the usual
>   arithmetic conversions (covered in Arithmetic Conversions) are performed to
>   convert them to a common type.
>
> If both operands are of pointer types or if one is a pointer type and the
>   other is a constant expression that evaluates to 0, pointer conversions are
>   performed to convert them to a common type.
>
> If both operands are of reference types, reference conversions are
>   performed to convert them to a common type.
>
> If both operands are of type void, the common type is type void.
>
> If both operands are of the same user-defined type, the common type is 
>   that type.
>
> If the operands have different types and at least one of the operands 
>   has user-defined type then the language rules are used to
>   determine the common type. (See warning below.)

And then there is a caution:

> If the types of the second and third operands are not identical, then
>   complex type conversion rules, as specified in the C++ Standard, are
>   invoked. These conversions may lead to unexpected behavior including
>   construction and destruction of temporary objects. For this reason, we
>   strongly advise you to either (1) avoid using user-defined types as
>   operands with the conditional operator or (2) if you do use
>   user-defined types, then explicitly cast each operand to a common
>   type.

Probably, this is the reason,  Apple deactivated this implicit conversion in LLVM.

So, if/else seems to be more appropriate in your case.

Comment: He isn't using operands of some user defined type. He is using operands that are pointers. There will be no conversion of objects. There would be at most a conversion of pointers to a different type, which the compiler then refuses to do. It doesn't convert two object pointers to a pointer to a common superclass.

Comment: The third use case in MS compilers is applied - conversion on pointers, which may not bi implemented in LLVM. Nothing is said about conversion of objects.