# Throwing with the ternary operator

Tags: c++

This compiles:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

int main(){
  if(true)
    throw A();
  else
    throw B();  
}
```

, but

```
struct A{};
struct B{};

int main(){
  throw( true ?  A() : B() );
}
```

won't.

Can I throw with the ternary operator?

Comment: `A` and `B` are different types, so the expression `true ? A() : B()` is ill-typed (it'd have to be either an A or a B).

Comment: That's so illegible.

Comment: The compiler error should have called out that `A` and `B` are incompatible.  gcc gives `error: incompatible operand types ('A' and 'B')`

Comment: @Almo Matter of taste. I find the ternary operator version easier to read.

Comment: This isn't a dupe; the dupe is referring to a compiler crash when `throw` is inside the ternary operator, but this question has it outside (and it's about a type error).

Comment: Is there a means to retract a close vote? You're right, it's not a dupe.

Comment: @Almo It appears to have been reopened.

Comment: What geniuses voted to close this as a duplicate of an obviously unrelated question?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Somebody who only skimmed the other question, voted to close, realised their mistake, and reopened it. That idiot. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sounds like I'm in a pretty bad position to criticize people for acting rashly...!

Comment: You also can't `std::cout << (true? 1 : "nope")`. Hardly a surprise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an exception be thrown from the ternary operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848132/can-an-exception-be-thrown-from-the-ternary-operator)

Comment: @PaoloM We already went thourgh this once.  It is not a duplicate of that.  If anything it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842095/incompatible-operand-types-when-using-ternary-conditional-operator

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, I've noticed too late :P This question does not have **anything** to do with *thowing*...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`A` and `B` are different, incompatible types, so the expression `true ? A() : B()` is ill-typed (it'd have to be either an `A` or a `B`).

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator needs to have the same type(or something convertible to the same type) on both paths otherwise the compiler can't reason about type safety.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a result from the conditional operator, the types needs to be somehow compatible. If the types are not compatible, you can still throw from a ternary operator, though:

```
condition? throw A(): throw B();
```

Although all compilers I tried do compile the above statement, it seems to be illegal: according to 5.16 [expr.cond] paragraph 2, first bullet "The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly parenthesized) throw-expression (15.1); ...". To counter that constraint it is possible to use something like

```
condition? (throw A()), true: throw B()
```