# Return type of decltype when applied to ternary(?:) expression

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

When I look into a code snippet for a possible implementation of [std::common_type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)

```
template <class ...T> struct common_type;

template <class T>
struct common_type<T> {
    typedef decay_t<T> type;
};

template <class T, class U>
struct common_type<T, U> {
    typedef decay_t<decltype(true ? declval<T>() : declval<U>())> type;
};

template <class T, class U, class... V>
struct common_type<T, U, V...> {
    typedef common_type_t<common_type_t<T, U>, V...> type;
};
```

The part how to get a common type for two template argument makes me confused.It is a usage of ternary operator with decltype.

As I known, whether to return the second or third operand is decided by the value of first operand. In this snippet, the first operand is **true** which means the return value of expression will always be **`declval<T>()`**. If it is what i thought which make no sense... Therefore, I have tried the following test

```
int iii = 2;
float fff = 3.3;
std::cout << typeid(decltype(false? std::move(iii):std::move(fff))).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(decltype(std::move(iii))).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(decltype(false ? iii : fff)).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(decltype(true ? iii : fff)).name() << std::endl;

// [02:23:37][ryu@C++_test]$ g++ -std=c++14 -g common_type.cpp
// output 
// f
// i
// f
// f
```

Comparing with the running result, The result what i though should be like as follows

```
int iii = 2;
float fff = 3.3;
std::cout << typeid(decltype(false ? iii : fff)).name() << std::endl; // should return f;
std::cout << typeid(decltype(true ? iii : fff)).name() << std::endl;  // should return i;
```

Anyone when can help to explain why the running result is different ?

In other words, what's the return result of decltype when it is applied on a ternary expression?

Comment: In your example code, the value in `iii` is converted to `float` type, since the result of ternary is the "widest" type.

Comment: I thought even if the second and third operands are not in the same type, implicitly conversion will not happen. Because **(true ? 1 : 2.0)** will return 1 instead of 1.0.  As per @T.C's wonderful explanation I have got the point. thanks all the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of an expression is a *compile-time* property. The value of the first operand in a conditional expression (and hence the branch selected), is, in general, a *run-time* thing, so it can't possibly affect the expression's type.

Instead, a complicated set of rules (more than a page of standardese, most of which I quoted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706480/why-does-stdistringstream-appear-to-resolve-differently-to-stdifstream-in-th/24706610#24706610)) is used to determine what the "common type" of the second and third operands is, and the conditional expression is of that type. `std::common_type` merely leverages the existing rules in the core language.