# Is this ternary operation with istreams safe?

Tags: c++, c++11, istream

```
decltype(std::cin)&& is = (argc < 2 ? std::move(std::cin) : std::ifstream(argv[1]));
```

Is this dangerous? Is there a simpler/less dangerous way?

It works fine. Example:

```
int i = 42;
is >> i; // enter 50
std::cout << i; // 50
```

Comment: Let's put it this way: if you have to spend time thinking about whether doing something like this is safe, you probably shouldn't do it regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to exactly how safe your version is. However, personally, I wouldn't want to *move* `std::cin` or bind to an `std::ifstream` unless I knew it was open(able). I favour opening the `std::ifstream` first (if it has been specified in the `argv`) and then binding to a `std::istream&` if `is_open()` else bind to `std::cin`.

I do *this* all the time and it is perfectly safe:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream ifs;

    if(argc > 1)
    {
        ifs.open(argv[1]);
        // check error and maybe exit
    }

    std::istream& is = ifs.is_open() ? ifs : std::cin;

    // ...
}
```

The answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706480/why-does-stdistringstream-appear-to-resolve-differently-to-stdifstream-in-th) may also be of interest.